# Can I implement FIFO to between requester and arbiter?

Tags: fpga, vhdl

There is multiple requester connected to Arbiter. Requester is placed far from the Arbiter and  leading to long nets. Because of this there is a timing violation. So, FIFO can be implemented  meet the timing violation??

Comment: Which "below" problem?

Comment: The ready and valid signals are tailored for FIFO handshaking. So, YES.

Comment: Thank you @Mitu Raj. May I know how ? Any reference document I can go through!!

Comment: Take a FIFO. Learn about its full empty enqueue and dequeue signals and connect using a glue logic. Or maybe not even a glue logic is required.

Comment: Okay. How to handle a_addr and a_len?? I can directly map read and write data to FIFO.

Comment: You can put two fifos. One for address, write-data and length as a concatenated packet, and one for read-data.

Comment: Okay. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use FIFOs. They will increase the latency through the memory subsystem, but they'll have no effect on throughput.

Comment: Thank you. How to handle a_addr and a_len ??

Comment: They get a FIFO, too.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you’re using AXI. Your FPGA flow should have library register slices (essentially a shallow FIFO) to break up clock domains when dealing in the same clock domain, or more involved solutions with asynchronous FIFOs for dealing with unrelated clocks.

These elements will be parameterized macros. You define the AXI ports you need, and the flow will create the template to instance them.